# bash comparing multiple column in two files with different length

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have following data set in text file

**data.txt**

```
d1,40,gold
d2,30,silver
d3,20,bronze
d4,10,iron
d5,5,wood
d6,20,gold
d7,10,wood
d8,5,gold
d9,10,silver
 .
 .
 .
```

**def.txt**

```
gold,40
silver,30
bronze,20
iron,10
wood,5
```

what I need is to compare data with my definition file, and add status as "ok" or "nok" in main file. As the data file is very big, I am able to figure out with while loop, but it is taking very long time. Is there any optimized way ?

**data.txt**

```
d1,40,gold,ok
d2,30,silver,ok
d3,20,bronze,ok
d4,10,iron,ok
d5,5,wood,ok
d6,20,gold,nok
d7,10,wood,nok
d8,5,gold,nok
d9,10,silver,nok
```

Comment: The only way to decide if (another) answer is faster, we would need to know your current solution and measure time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through single [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command I think it would be faster than using a while-loop. You can test it how fast is by [`time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/time.1posix.html) command in front of the command and see if it's fast ;)

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ arr[$2]=$2 $1; next } 
    { print $0, (arr[$2]==$2 $3?"ok":"nok") }' OFS=, def.txt data.txt
d1,40,gold,ok
d2,30,silver,ok
d3,20,bronze,ok
d4,10,iron,ok
d5,5,wood,ok
d6,20,gold,nok
d7,10,wood,nok
d8,5,gold,nok
d9,10,silver,nok
```

#### Explanation:

- `NR` is set to 1 when the first record read by *awk* and incrementing for each next records reading either in single or multiple input files until all read finished.
- `FNR` is set to 1 when the first record read by *awk* and incrementing for each next records reading in current file and reset back to 1 for the next input file if multiple input files.
- so `NR == FNR` is true for the first file only *def.txt*
- `arr[$2]=$2 $1`; creates an associative array named `arr` with the key as `$2` and copy second and first fields as its value.
- The `next` token skips to executing rest of the commands and those will only execute actually for next file(s) except first.
- This `print $0` prints the whole line of *data.txt* and `(arr[$2]==$2 $3?"ok":"nok")` (known as Ternary operator (`condition?"if-true":"if-false"`)checks if key value in `arr[$2]` was equal with values of `$2 $3` (second and third fields) in *data.txt* then print *"ok"* else *"nok"*.
- This will also work if your data.txt file and def.txt files are not **sort-ed**.

Comment: Highly appreciated, This solution was really fast !

Comment: final question, is this comparison can be done in more than 2 files, and link to this documentation is will help me more.

Comment: @user261334 by some modification on this command, yes it can be done but it's relates to the **input files**. so if you want to do something else you have to open new question for that. thanks